# Is it possible to use mobile phone as security key in SSH?

Tags: ssh, google-authenticator, fido, fido-u2f, yubikey

I recently gone through a blog that explains usage of Yubikeys in SSH. I wonder whether I could use the same method without Yubikey (using my android phone)?

The reffered blog: https://swjm.blog/the-complete-guide-to-ssh-with-fido2-security-keys-841063a04252

The main objective is whenever I try to SSH into a host system from my system, it should pop up Allow/Deny in my mobile phone, like the Google login works

I tried different alternatives of Yubikeys like IDmelon, but couldn't help since my systems are linux based(Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Using FIDO security keys for storing SSH keys is currently [implemented in
OpenSSH](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/PROTOCOL.u2f) using middleware that uses USB transport.

To use your Android phone as a USB security key would require your phone to be able to communicate using FIDO's CTAP protocol over USB. Android does not support  that natively, and I don't know of any app that does, nor if such an app would be allowed to do that on Android.

Android does support CTAP over a tunnel towards web browsers (called hybrid transport, aka [cross-device authentication](https://passkeys.dev/docs/reference/terms/#cross-device-authentication-cda)), but that is not supported by OpenSSH.